# How to convert List(Of TaskUserAssignment) to Long in UiPath

Tags: types

[Error Iamge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY5pb.png)

I was trying to assign task to the Orchestrator in UiPath and I received this error And I am trying to convert to every other data type but there is no use. How to solve this issue to move forward in the automation process